# DIV over table cell (Firefox issue)

Tags: html, css

I want div to be appeared over table cell (filling the entire space of the cell, div width=100% and height=100%) on mouseover event.

In IE8 and Chrome it looks like i want it to be, but in Firefox div appears beyond the boundaries of the table cell.

[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegEF/RDq8Q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `position: relative;` on the `td` element. Firefox ignores this value on table cells, see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168).

To circumvent this beahaviour you can create a single child of the `td` which serves as a wrapper.

```
<td>
    <div class="table-cell-wrapper">Your absolute positioned content here</div>
</td>
```

And with this CSS you give the wrapper the dimensions of the table cell.

```
.table-cell-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I updated yout jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RDq8Q/2/. You need to adjust the exact posionting again, but yout overlay works now.